# Adding animation to ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Hi I am trying to add an animation such as fade in/fade out or slide to .load . I have attached a fiddle of the basic structure but firstly my ajax calls are not working on fiddle (I tried full urls) but they work on the test site.

I tried adding .fade() to the end of the function but this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
            $(".vCard").click(function(){
                $("#mainContent").load("ajax/vCard.php").fade();
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/craigie2204/mhUx7/

Comment: If you want to mimic ajax calls in jsFiddle, you will need to modify your URLs to point to jsFiddle's own. See here: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one thing just `.hide()` it first then add the `.fadeIn()`:

change to this:

```
 $("#mainContent").load("ajax/vCard.php").hide().fadeIn();
```

or better to hide it with `css` and just add the `.fadeIn()`:

**CSS:**

```
#mainContent{
   display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $("#mainContent").load("ajax/vCard.php").fadeIn();
```

But you have to do within the callback handler in the `.load()` method of jquery:

```
$("#mainContent").load("ajax/vCard.php", function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(); // this will be animated when load gets completed.
});
```

Comment: how can it works if `load()` make an async request? The `fadeIn()` call should be set as callback of the `load()` function. Here the documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/ .
If you are trying in local environment the response could be so fast that seems to work because the delay of the `fadeIn()` function gives you the illusion that it is triggered after the content is loaded, but it isn't.

Comment: @marquez you are right, this should be done exactly the way you suggested, What seem to me that op is perhaps doing something like this, anyway this should be done the way you suggested and i just updated the answer.

Comment: @Jai glad to help! Maybe an upvote could be really appreciated!

Comment: It seems you didn't posted an answer here.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I was happy with the answer Jai gave but knew that it needed some tinkering but was happy to do this myself,  it was the best overall answer. Thank you for your input Marquez

Answer (score 0):

Try `.fadeIn(1500)`

That should work

**Resources**

[where do i put jQuery .fade() function in ajax success callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882687/where-do-i-put-jquery-fade-function-in-ajax-success-callback)

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: Hi thanks I tried this but I think because Ajax is async it is loading before it comes on to the page and the animation is already done

Comment: use the `.success` on the ajax as provided in another answer in combination with the `fadeIn`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't work. I am getting no javascript errors but the animation is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $(".vCard").click(function(){
>     var _div = $("#mainContent");
>     _div.load("ajax/vCard.php",function(){
>         _div.fade();
>     });
>   });
> ```
>
> Blockquote

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't work. I am getting no javascript errors but the animation is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ajax function, so you can use different statut like :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url, //Set you url here
   data: getData,
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(data) {
      $(this).fadeIn(400); //When you loaded your ajax page, Fade In to show. If you want to parse what you get use '.html(data)'
   }
});
```

Comment: Does this go inside the .click function?

Comment: Yes ! You can put this function in your click